# How can I get the sub-item type of a TObjectList<T> purely by RTTI information (i.e. without using any actual object instance) in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, generics, rtti, tobjectlist

I'm implementing generic code for streaming arbitrary Delphi objects using RTTI, and in order to get this to work (more specifically, in order to get the loading part to work), I need to somehow get the sub-item type of a `TObjectList<T>` field without making use of any actual object instance.

The obvious reason for the requirement to not use any actual object instance is that in the case of loading an object from a stream (based solely on the knowledge of the class type of the object to be loaded), I won't have any instance at all available before the loading has completed - I will rather only have access to the pure RTTI data of the class in question.

An example of such a class that I'd like to be able to load is the following:

```
TTestClass = class(TObject)
public
   test_list : TList<string>;
end;
```

What I want is to be able to conclude that the `test_list` field is a generic `TList<T>` where `T` is `string` (i.e. in order to know what data to expect from the stream for the sub-items).

If the class did instead look as follows:

```
TTestClassWithArr = class(TObject)
public
   test_arr : array of string;
end;
```

I could use the `ElementType()` method of the `TRttiDynamicArrayType` RTTI class of the `test_arr` field to extract this information purely through RTTI, but I cannot find any corresponding such explicit RTTI type for `TObjectList<T>`.

Another Stack Overflow question ([Delphi Rtti: how to get objects from `TObjectList<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497843/delphi-rtti-how-to-get-objects-from-tobjectlistt)) is related, but does indeed use an actual instance of the object that the RTTI data reflects to "cheat" in order to get to the sub-items, which, again, is not an option for me since these sub-items do not exist at the time I must know this.

It really feels like there should be some way to do this by solely using the RTTI information of the class though, since all the type information is obviously present for it at compile-time, regardless of object instantiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no RTTI generated for Generic parameters.  The only way to discover the value of `T` in a Generic container like `TList<T>` is to get the `TRttiType` for the target field itself, call its `ToString()` method to get its class name as a string, and parse out the substring that is between the brackets.  For example:

```
uses
  ..., System.StrUtils, System.Rtti;

var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  s: string;
  OpenBracket, CloseBracket: Integer;
  ...
begin
  ...
  s := Ctx.GetType(TTestClass).GetField('test_list').FieldType.ToString; // returns 'TList<System.string>'
  OpenBracket := Pos('<', s);
  CloseBracket := PosEx('>', s, OpenBracket+1);
  s := Copy(s, OpenBracket+1, CloseBracket-OpenBracket-1); // returns 'System.string'
  // if multiple Generic parameters are present, they will be separated by commas...
  ...
end;
```

Once you have extracted the Generic parameter as a string, you can use `TRttiContext.FindType()` if you need to access the RTTI for that type.

With that said, the following code provides a bunch of RTTI helpers:

[DSharp.Core.Reflection.pas](https://code.google.com/p/delphisorcery/source/browse/trunk/Source/Core/DSharp.Core.Reflection.pas) (Google Code)

[DSharp.Core.Reflection.pas](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/dsharp/src/ad7c5983505f0117f1347f92d2bb96c07bdfda94/Source/Core/DSharp.Core.Reflection.pas?at=master) (BitBucket)

Amongst other things, it defines a `TRttiTypeHelper` class helper that adds a `GetGenericArguments()` method to `TRttiType`:

```
TRttiTypeHelper = class helper for TRttiType
...
public 
  ...
  function GetGenericArguments: TArray<TRttiType>;
  ...
end;
```

Internally, `GetGenericArguments()` uses the same technique I mention above.  With it, you can do this instead:

```
uses
  ..., System.Rtti, DSharp.Core.Reflection;

var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  arr: TArray<TRttiType>;
  typ: TRttiType;
  s: string;
  ...
begin
  ...
  arr := Ctx.GetType(TTestClass).GetField('test_list').FieldType.GetGenericArguments;
  typ := arr[0]; // returns RTTI for System.String
  s := typ.ToString; // returns 'System.string'
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for this solid reply, but before I accept it as a final answer, could you please explain to me how the `.ToString()` method of the `TRttiType` instance for the `test_list` field obviously has access to this information when it prints the full string that you advise me to manually parse? The correct answer would in that case seem to be that there _does_ exist RTTI information about this, although it's not accessible through the defined Delphi RTTI methods?

Comment: Also, while researching this myself in parallel, I found the `TRttiEnumerationType` which seems to be very promising for my objective with its `.UnderlyingType` property. Could you (or anyone else) possibly comment on that? Unfortunately I'm currently having some other problems with that solution, as described in the following other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922600/delphi-rtti-how-can-i-test-if-an-unknown-tvalue-reflects-an-object-that-is-any

Comment: `TRttiType.ToString()` simply returns the value of the `TRttiNamedObject.Name` property. `TRttiType` overrides the virtual `GetName()` property getter to retrieve the type name from the `System.TypInfo` RTTI pointed to by the `TRttiType.Handle` property (eg: `PTypeInfo(Handle)^.Name`).  That `Name` value is generated by the compiler and stored as-is in the RTTI of the actual `TList<String>` class (not the `TList<T>` class, which has no RTTI of its own because it is not a concrete class).  Again, there is no RTTI (from either the `System.Rtti` or `System.TypInfo` unit) for the Generic arguments

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, but what's up with the `TRttiEnumerationType` and its `.UnderlyingType` property then, as mentioned in my comment above? Also doesn't the following statement "_In Win32, generics and methods do not have run-time type information (RTTI), **but instantiated types do have RTTI**. An instantiated type is the combination of a generic with a set of parameters_" over at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Overview_of_Generics contradict your assertion about lack of such RTTI information? (I'm sure you're right though, I just need to be really certain about it)

Comment: An enum is based on different types (byte, word, integer) depending on the number of elements, and compiler options. `UnderlyingType` tells you the base type. That has **absolutely nothing** to do with this discussion about Generics RTTI. And no, the documentation does not contradict my statement, it agrees with it. `TList<T>` itself does not have its own RTTI, but `TList<String>` (a concrete instantiation of `TList<T>`) does. Information about Generic parameters and their types **is not stored in an instantiated type's RTTI**. You have to hunt for it manually, as I explained.

Comment: Thanks for making all this clear, answer accepted, and well-deserved too. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for a solution about this and I had an ideia that I'd like to share with you. That solution uses rtti and get the method's argument "Add" from a list(TList,TObjectList,etc). In my function I just return the Class Type, but you can easyly implements to primivite types. I hope it can help someone. Regards.

Folow:

```
class function TUtilRtti.GetSubTypeItemClassFromList(ObjectList: TObject): TClass;
var
  ctxRtti  : TRttiContext;
  typeRtti : TRttiType;
  atrbRtti : TCustomAttribute;
  methodRtti: TRttiMethod;
  parameterRtti: TRttiParameter;
begin
  result := nil;

  ctxRtti  := TRttiContext.Create;
  typeRtti := ctxRtti.GetType( ObjectList.ClassType );
  methodRtti := typeRtti.GetMethod('Add');
  for parameterRtti in methodRtti.GetParameters do
  begin
    if SameText(parameterRtti.Name,'Value') then
    begin
      if parameterRtti.ParamType.IsInstance then
        result := parameterRtti.ParamType.AsInstance.MetaclassType;
      break;
    end;
  end;
  ctxRtti.Free;
end;
```

Sample

```
...
var
  List: TList<TCustomer>;
begin
  List := TList<Customer>.Create();

  ShowMessage(TUtilRtti.GetSubTypeItemClassFromList(List).ClassName);
end;
```