# How can I test if an unknown Delphi RTTI TValue reflects an object that is ANY type of generic TList<> (or at least TEnumerable<>)?

Tags: delphi, generics, rtti, typechecking

In Delphi, if I have a `TValue` instance reflecting an unknown object, how can I test if this object is an instance of ANY kind of generic `TEnumerable<>` (or even better, also *which* specific generic enumerable type it is an instance of, e.g. `TList<>`)?

**NOTE: I already know how to easily check its *exact* type, i.e. with the `.BaseType` property of the corresponding `TRttiType` of the `TValue`, resulting in for example `TList<string>`, but what I want to test is rather if it is a `TList<>` of *any* sub-item type**.

To exemplify how this hypothetical code "IsAnyKindOfGenericEnumerable()" would work, here is some example code:

```
var
   LContext : TRttiContext;
   obj_1_rtti_value : TValue;
   obj_2_rtti_value : TValue;
   obj_3_rtti_value : TValue;
   obj_1_rtti_type : TRttiType;
   obj_2_rtti_type : TRttiType;
   obj_3_rtti_type : TRttiType;

LContext := TRttiContext.Create();

{
...
obj_1_rtti_value is set to a TValue reflection of a TList<string> object here
obj_2_rtti_value is set to a TValue reflection of a plain TObject object here
obj_3_rtti_value is set to a TValue reflection of a TQueue<integer> object here
...
}

obj_1_rtti_type := LContext.GetType(obj_1_rtti_value.TypeInfo);
obj_2_rtti_type := LContext.GetType(obj_2_rtti_value.TypeInfo);
obj_3_rtti_type := LContext.GetType(obj_3_rtti_value.TypeInfo);

IsAnyKindOfGenericEnumerable(obj_1_rtti_type); //Would return true
IsAnyKindOfGenericEnumerable(obj_2_rtti_type); //Would return false
IsAnyKindOfGenericEnumerable(obj_3_rtti_type); //Would return true
```

And again, the very best thing would be if I could also detect *which* kind of `TEnumerable<>` type it is, like for example:

```
IsAnyKindOfGenericEnumerable(obj_1_rtti_type); //Will return true + `TList<>`
IsAnyKindOfGenericEnumerable(obj_2_rtti_type); //Will return false
IsAnyKindOfGenericEnumerable(obj_3_rtti_type); //Will return true + `TQueue<>`
```

I have tried:

```
if obj_1_rtti_type is TRttiEnumerationType then
begin
   //...
end;
```

but for some reason this evaluates to `false`, which I'm completely at loss as to why that is? The expression `value_type.BaseType.Name` does indeed  evaluate to `'TEnumerable<System.string>'` in this case, but there really has to be some other way than to manually parse this string in order to accomplish my objective, right?

Finally, the goal must be accomplished solely using the RTTI info, that is, any "cheating" by referring to the real object behind the TValue is not permitted (for reasons outside the scope of this question).

Comment: Why the downvotes without explanations?

Comment: Some twerp is seemingly obsessively downvoting all my questions, no matter what they are about. Therefore, in order to avoid this from unfairly affecting my "reputation" (my ability to post new questions etc), I ask you to please upvote this question if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no RTTI generated for Generic types themselves (they don't exist at runtime), and each specific instantiation (like `TList<string>`) is a *distinct class type with its own distinct RTTI*.  You would have to check for *each individual type*, it is not possible to test for *any Generic type*.  Parsing class names is the only way to detect Generic types.

1. use `TRttiType.Name` to get the class name as a string (`'TList<System.string>'`).
2. parse it to detect the presence of angle brackets (`'<>'`).
3. extract the substring between the brackets (`'System.string'`)
4. walk the ancestor tree looking for an ancestor whose `TRttiType.Name` is `'TEnumerable<...>'`, where `...` is the extracted substring (`'TEnumerable<System.string>'`).

However, this approach fails for class types that derive from `TEnumerable<T>` but do not have Generics parameters themselves, eg:

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TEnumerable<string>)
  end;
```

To account for that, ignore steps 1-3 and jump right to step 4 by itself, ignoring whatever value appears between the brackets, eg:

```
function IsAnyKindOfGenericEnumerable(AType: TRttiType): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  while AType <> nil do
  begin
    Result := StartsText('TEnumerable<', AType.Name);
    if Result then Exit;
    AType := AType.BaseType;
  end;
end;
```

As for `TRttiEnumerationType`, it represents [**enumerated types**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Simple_Types#Enumerated_Types) (ie: `type typeName = (val1, ...,valn);`).  It has nothing to do with `TEnumerable<T>`. That is why the `is` operator is always returning False for you - none of the RTTI types you are testing represent enums.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (accepted), but do you (or anyone else) have any idea why this question has been downvoted twice now, without any explanations in the comments whatsoever? I think it's a perfectly valid question to ask, which many other people would probably also like to have the answer of?